# Schröder-Bernstein theorem and injective maps

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am a bit confused about the statement of the **Schröder-Bernstein theorem** which states the following:

> Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are sets, and that $f : A \to B$ and $g : B \to A$ are injective mappings. Then
>   there exists a bijection $h : A \to B$.

- Can it be directly infered that the $f$ and $g$ must only be bijective otherwise that would contradict that both $A$ and $B$ are the same size easily infered from $f$ and $g$?
- And if so, why then the statement of theorem describes $f$ and $g$ as "injective" rather than "bijective"?

Comment: There is no need for $f$ or $g$ to be bijection. If $|A|=|B|$, and the sets are infinite, there are *always* injections each way that are not bijections.

Comment: The entire purpose of Schröder-Bernstein is to generate a bijection from two injections.

Answer (score 5):

No, in general the maps $f$ and $g$ need not be bijective.

Simple counterexample: Let $A=\mathbb N$ and $B=\{2n:n\in\mathbb N\}$. Then you can take say $f(x)=4x$ and $g(x)=x/2$. Both are injective, but $f$ is not bijective.

Comment: If you take $g(x)=x$ then neither is injective (your example would be more striking), but Schröder-Bernstein would still give you that some bijection exists.

Comment: @MarkS. Great point!

Answer (score 5):

No, the Schroder-Bernstein theorem only tells you that there exists a *different* map $h$ which is a bijection, not that $f$ and $g$ are bijections.  For instance, suppose $A=[0,1]$ and $B=[0,2]$.  You can take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x/4$, and then $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ are both injections.  Neither $f$ nor $g$ is a bijection however; Schroder-Bernstein just tells you that some different map $A\to B$ must be a bijection.

What's going on here is that if $A$ and $B$ are infinite and the same size, it is possible to have an injection $A\to B$ which is not surjective.